# Greystripe ads with MonoTouch?

Tags: c#, objective-c, binding, xamarin.ios, ads

Has anybody integrated [greystripe](http://www.greystripe.com) ads into their app built with MonoTouch?

If so whats the best way to go about it?

Greystripe provides and SDK and guide, but it deals with objective-c and editing in xcode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to let know anyone who finds this questiom

You can find MonoTouch Greystrpe Bindings [here](https://github.com/dalexsoto/AlexTouch.Greystripe)

Comment: Will this work with the newer versions of the greystripe sdk?

Answer (score 1):

You an use btouch to create the MonoTouch bindings to the ObjC SDK

From http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/advanced_topics/binding_objective-c_types

> The new btouch tool for MonoTouch (and bmac for MonoMac) simplifies binding an Objective-C API and does the heavy lifting for you: registering the selectors, taking care of invoking the proper handle for overwritten classes, doing parameter checking and doing some of the common marshaling required for your project.