# MonoTouch bindings for ad network that has full screen ads?

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, fullscreen, ads, mobclix

Are there any MonoTouch binding for an ad-network with full screen ads? The only one I have found is AdMob which doesn't have the full screen ads. Options are (among many) Greystrype and MobClix but haven't seen any MT bindings.

Related question (without the actual bindings): 
[Greystripe ads with MonoTouch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9189024/greystripe-ads-with-monotouch)

Wondering if this is because there are issues creating the MT bindings against the various ad providers or nobody has shared their work. Would like to hear some input before I start trying to make the bindings myself :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to let know anyone who finds this question

Here is [Greystrpe MonoTouch Binding](https://github.com/dalexsoto/AlexTouch.Greystripe) and here is [MobClix MonoTouch Binding](https://github.com/dalexsoto/AlexTouch.Mobclix)

Also thanks to Christer Nordvik for this ;)

Answer (score 1):

> Wondering if this is because there are issues creating the MT bindings

AFAIK there's no technical issue that would prevent binding them.

> Would like to hear some input before I start trying to make the bindings myself :-)

There are already bindings for several others (ad providers) and for Apple's iAd (which has full screen ads IIRC) available for MonoTouch. My **guess** is that people are happy with their current providers - at least happy enough not to bind new libraries.

However since you have a different requirement (full screen ads) that *might* not be available in existing (binded) providers (I have not checked them) then you should definitively look at `btouch` and [bind](http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/advanced_topics/binding_objective-c_types) one (or both) of them (and share the bindings :-).

Comment: Hmm, seems I actually have to do some real coding? No copy/paste programming? Ok then, I'll bind one of them and publish the code somewhere :-)